# How to change the language property of a dll/exe on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, wix

How do you change the language property of a Windows DLL or EXE? The property I am talking about can be seen if you right-click on a DLL and go "Properties" > "Details". Something from the command line would be preferred.

*Background...*

I am trying to get rid of a warning when building a Windows installation package using WiX. The warning is:

> LGHT1076: ICE60: The file somedll.dll
>   is not a Font, and its version is not
>   a companion file reference. It should
>   have a language specified in the
>   Language column.

If you add a `DefaultLanguage` attribute for the file within the WiX project file, this changes to:

> LGHT1101: The DefaultLanguage '0' was
>   used for file 'somedll.dll' which has
>   no language. Specifying a language
>   that is different from the actual file
>   may result in unexpected versioning
>   behavior during a repair or while
>   patching. Either specify a value for
>   DefaultLanguage or put the language in
>   the version information resource to
>   eliminate this warning.

I'm really not sure what the first solution they suggest means ... didn't I just "specify a value for DefaultLanguage?" So I'm trying the second solution, which I'm guessing is the language property of the file? I am building `somedll.dll` from source, so if it is something that has to be done when building, I might be able to do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since I had access to the source, I was able to change the version resource file to include the language in this case. The specific library was Qt, the fix can be seen in [QTBUG-16583](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-16583).

Still not sure how one would do it without access to source.

Comment: External reference with detail is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

A file's language is an attribute of its versioninfo resource. WiX reads it to autopopulate the language (and version) columns in the .msi File table.

Comment: Do you happen to know, in the case where this autopopulation fails, how to tell WiX what it should be? That is, to put a value into the Language column when it can't be auto-generated from the file itself, but allow the user to provide it? That *seems* to be what the warning is suggesting, but apparently the `DefaultLanguage` attribute isn't sufficient.